# Solve the equation $(2^m-1) = (2^n-1)k^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find the solutions to the equation $(2^m-1) = (2^n-1)k^2$ where $m,n,k$ are positive integers.

One solution is $m = n$.

Since $2^n-1 \mid 2^m-1$, it follows that $n \mid m$ because $\gcd(2^m-1,2^n-1) = 2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$. Let $m = nd$ for some positive integer $d$. Then we have $$\dfrac{2^m-1}{2^n-1} = \dfrac{2^{nd}-1}{2^n-1} = 2^{(d-1)n}+2^{(d-2)n}+\cdots+2^n+1 = k^2.$$ Therefore we can write $k^2 = 1u \ldots u_2$ where $u = \underbrace{00 \ldots 0}_{n-1 \text{ }\text{zeros}}1$ with $u$ appearing $d-1$ times. How can we continue from here?

Comment: What do you mean $u_2$?  Is this supposed to be $u,$ ?

Comment: @ErickWong It is in binary.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: possible hint : Wieferich prime  ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Could you be more specific? It's true that if $m$ is prime then $k$ is only divisible by Wieferich primes.  However, I'm not aware of much that can be said when $m$ is not prime; perhaps we can then decompose via cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: my thought was more towards m being prime but you can also say if m isn't then it divides by mersennes that may have that property so k either divides by Wieferich primes, or primes that divide the leftover part.

Comment: İs this olimpiad question?

Comment: I can semi relate this to the problem I tried with lucas lehmer testing as ${(2^n-1)}^2 = (2^{n+1}-1)\cdot(2^{n-1}-1)+(2^{n-1})$

Comment: Putting $d=2$ and $n=3$,  $2^3+1=3^2$ yielding the solution $2^6-1=(2^3-1)3^2$.  But this looks hard to generalise.

Comment: @AdamBailey the equation in your example is Catalan's conjecture (now proven). I wondered if its uniqueness in this regard lends something to the problem.

Comment: @RobertFrost Yes, I was thinking of the conjecture when I said it looks hard to generalise, thanks for reminding me of its name.

Answer (score 8):

If $d:=m/n$ is even, let $d=2r$. Then
$$k^2=\frac{2^m-1}{2^n-1}=\frac{2^{nr}-1}{2^n-1}(2^{nr}+1).$$
Since $k^2$ factors into two coprime positive integers, both of the two factors must be perfect square. Then $2^{nr}+1=z^2$ leads to $(z-1)(z+1)=2^{nr}$, so $z-1$ and $z+1$ are both powers of $2$. This only happens when $z=3,nr=3$. It remains to check that $k\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ when $n=1,r=3$ and $k=3$ when $n=3,r=1$.

Therefore, the only solution is $(m,n,k)=(6,3,3)$ given that $d$ is even.

---

If $d$ is odd, there are two cases.

**Case 1:** For $n=2l$, consider the Pell equation
$$x^2-(2^{2l}-1)y^2=1\tag{1}\label{1}$$
It is easy to see that $(2^l,1)$ is the fundamental solution of \eqref{1}.

The equation $2^{nd}-1=(2^n-1)k^2$ implies that $(2^{ld},k)$ is also a solution of \eqref{1}. So we have
$$2^{ld}+k\sqrt{2^{2l}-1}=\biggl(2^l+\sqrt{2^{2l}-1}\biggr)^t$$
for integer $t>0$. Take the reciprocal to get
$$2^{ld}-k\sqrt{2^{2l}-1}=\biggl(2^l-\sqrt{2^{2l}-1}\biggr)^t.$$
Let $s=\lfloor t/2\rfloor$, then
\begin{align}
2^{ld}&=\frac{1}{2}\Biggl(\biggl(2^l+\sqrt{2^{2l}-1}\biggr)^t+\biggl(2^l-\sqrt{2^{2l}-1}\biggr)^t\Biggr)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{s}\binom{t}{2i}2^{(t-2i)l}(2^{2l}-1)^i\\
&=\binom{t}{2s}2^{(t-2s)l}(2^{2l}-1)^{s}+2^{2l}\sum_{i=0}^{s-1}\binom{t}{2i}2^{(t-2i-2)l}(2^{2l}-1)^i.\\
\end{align}
Consider the exponent of $2$, we have
$$\nu_2\biggl(\binom{t}{2s}2^{(t-2s)l}(2^{2l}-1)^{s}\biggr)=(t-2s)l\leqslant l<2l\leqslant\nu_2\Biggl(2^{2l}\sum_{i=0}^{s-1}\binom{t}{2i}2^{(t-2i-2)l}(2^{2l}-1)^i\Biggr)$$
So $0<ld=\nu_2(2^{ld})\leqslant l$, which implies $d=1$.

**Case 2:** For $n=2l-1$, consider the Pell equation
$$x^2-(2^{2l}-2)y^2=1\tag{2}\label{2}$$
We claim that $(2^{2l}-1,2^l)$ is the fundamental solution of \eqref{2}.

Obviously, $(2^{2l}-1,2^l)$ is a solution of \eqref{2}. Let $(u,v)$ be the fundamental solution, then
$$2^{2l}-1+2^l\sqrt{2^{2l}-2}=\biggl(u+v\sqrt{2^{2l}-2}\biggr)^e$$
for integer $e>0$ and we have $2^{2l}-1\geqslant u^e$. Since it is easy to see that $u>2^l$, we get $e=1$ thus $(2^{2l}-1,2^l)=(u,v)$ is the fundamental solution as we claimed.

Because $2^{nd}-1=(2^n-1)k^2=(2^{2l-1}-1)k^2$ implies
$$(2^{nd+1}-1)^2-(2^{2l}-2)k^22^{nd+1}=(2^{nd+1}-1)^2-(2^{nd}-1)2^{nd+2}=1,$$
i.e. $(2^{nd+1}-1,k2^{(nd+1)/2})$ is also a solution of \eqref{2}, we have
$$2^{nd+1}-1+k2^{(nd+1)/2}\sqrt{2^{2l}-2}=\biggl(2^{2l}-1+2^l\sqrt{2^{2l}-2}\biggr)^t$$
for integer $t>0$. The same as above, we transform it to get
\begin{align}
2^{nd+1}&=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(2^{2l}-1+2^l\sqrt{2^{2l}-2}\right)^t+\left(2^{2l}-1-2^l\sqrt{2^{2l}-2}\right)^t\right)\\
&=1+\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor t/2\rfloor}\binom{t}{2i}(2^{2l}-1)^{t-2i}2^{2li}(2^{2l}-2)^i\\
&=1+(2^{2l}-1)^t+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor t/2\rfloor}\binom{t}{2i}(2^{2l}-1)^{t-2i}2^{(2l+1)i}(2^{2l-1}-1)^i\\
&=1+(-1)^t+(-1)^{t-1}t2^{2l}+2^{2l+1}R.
\end{align}
Note that
$$\nu_2\bigl(1+(-1)^t+(-1)^{t-1}t2^{2l}\bigr)=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{$t$ even}\\
2l, & \text{$t$ odd}
\end{cases}\leqslant 2l<2l+1\leqslant\nu_2(2^{2l+1}R).$$
So $1<nd+1=\nu_2(2^{nd+1})\leqslant2l=n+1$, which also implies $d=1$.

Therefore, we always get $d=1$ given that $d$ is odd.

---

From above, $(m,n,k)=(6,3,3),(n,n,1)$ are the only solutions of the equation.

---

### Background

W. Ljunggren had proved a theorem that for $n>2$, the equation
$$y^2=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$
has no solutions in integers for $|x|>1$, except $n=4,x=7$ and $n=5,x=3$.

This theorem will expel most cases of your equation and you can find a proof in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206645/on-a-result-attributed-to-w-ljunggren-and-t-nagell). It is a short proof based on the results of T. Nagell and K. Mahler.

For a self-contained answer to your question, I borrowed Ljunggren's idea to transform the equation into a Pell(-like) equation, and made use of the special setting of $x$ to finish my proof without the help of other results. However, the knowledge of Pell equation is required in advance.

Comment: @MathematicsisLife If you have any question about this proof, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Maybe this is not the right place to ask. I would like to ask a question at SE. But I can not express the question..

Comment: Is it possible to look at the my question?I want yo learn is my question  understandable?..

Comment: @MathematicsisLife I think you can just post your question, and edit to improve it if necessary.

Comment: The question will be downvoted.Ok.no problem.thank.you.

Comment: @Mercury perhaps of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414041/