# Is there a generalisation of Catalan's Conjecture hiding in the solution to $(2^m-1) = (2^n-1)k^2$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there a generalisation of Catalan's Conjecture hiding in the solution to $(2^m-1) = (2^n-1)k^2$?

I ask having noticed the similarity between the answer to this; [Solve the equation $(2^m-1) = (2^n-1)k^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411716/) and the conjecture.  Mercury's nontrivial solution is:

$3^2(2^3-1)=2^6-1$

$3^2(2^3-1)=(1+2^3)(2^3-1)$

Dividing throughout by $2^3-1$ we have the sole example of the Catalan statement:

$3^2=2^3-1$

Which suggests to me Mercury's answer may be a generalisation or special case of the (already proven) Catalan's conjecture.

The original question might therefore be generalised as follows:

Let $(2^{pn}-1) = (2^n-1)k^r$

Do $p,n,k,r$ in general obey Catalan's conjecture:

$k^r-p^n=1$

This might be thought of intuitively as; we know $3^2$ is the only perfect square ratio between two Mersenne numbers $M_q$ (where $q$ is not necessarily prime), but is it further the only perfect power?

And generalising further we might conjecture the same identity holds for:

$(p^{pn}-1) = (p^n-1)k^r$

Comment: That problem is almost covered by the theorem of Ljunggren, which may generalize to Nagell-Ljunggren equation
$x^n-1=(x-1)y^q$, where $x>1,y>1,n>2,q\geqslant2$. As you may find in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58697/a-geometric-series-equalling-a-power-of-an-integer), it is still not solved. If you take $n=2$ and require $x$ to be a power, then you get the Catalan's conjecture. You may combine two problems to the equation $x^m-1=(x^n-1)y^q$, but it contains no more interesting things.

Comment: @Mercury I extended my thinking a little in different ways ^^